# fpm installed, but not working on Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, debian, fpm

I am writing a script to build a debian for my project which requires fpm. For installing fpm, I have followed the instructions from the official site. gem installs it properly, and I can see it in the gems list. However, fpm command doesn't work. `fpm --version` returns `fpm` command not found. Whenever I try running a `which fpm` my cmd doesn't print any thing, no errors, no output etc.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

add fpm path to your path manually, on my Mac fpm path is `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fpm-1.11.0/bin`.

```
vim ~/.bash_profile, add a export line below:
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fpm-1.11.0/bin:$PATH
```

then exit and execute comand:

```
source ~/.bash_profile.
```